# Migrating to Automapper 4.2.1 from Automapper 2.2.1

Tags: wcf, unity-container, automapper

I have a project where I have been using automapper 2.2.1. I upgraded to 4.2.1 and am completely broken. I tried to follow [this](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/)
by changing all references to `Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Target>()` to `Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<Source, Target>()})`. I'm now broken bad and I cant seem to get it done.I'm getting "**System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException was unhandled by user code exception with Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information**", message. What am I missing. Code looks like this:

AutomapperTypeAdapterFactory

```
public class AutomapperTypeAdapterFactory : ITypeAdapterFactory
{
    public AutomapperTypeAdapterFactory()
    {
        //scan all assemblies finding Automapper Profile
        var profiles = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                                .GetAssemblies()
                                .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                                .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Profile));

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            foreach (var item in profiles)
            {
                if (item.FullName != "AutoMapper.SelfProfiler`2")
                    cfg.AddProfile(Activator.CreateInstance(item) as Profile);
            }
        });
    }

    public ITypeAdapter Create() => new AutomapperTypeAdapter();
}
```

Department Profile

```
public class DepartmentProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Department, DepartmentDto>();
        });
    }
}
```

UnityContainer

```
public static class Container
{
    static IUnityContainer _container = new UnityContainer();

    static Container()
    {
        var typeAdapterFactory = _container.Resolve<ITypeAdapterFactory>();
        TypeAdapterFactory.SetCurrent(typeAdapterFactory);
    }
    //other container resolutions....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In projects where I've moved away from the static configuration I've defined a few mapping profiles (generally a profile per application layer):

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
    }
}
```

I then configure my IoC (SimpleInjector, in my case) to find all profiles and add them to a single, unified configuration. I then register the `MapperConfiguration` in my container, as well as the `IMapper` object created from the same:

```
    public void ConfigureSimpleInjector(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

        container.RegisterAutoMapper();

        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        container.RegisterMvcIntegratedFilterProvider();

        container.Verify();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    }


public static Container RegisterAutoMapper(this Container container)
    {
        var profiles = typeof(AutoMapperRegistry).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(t)).Select(t => (Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(t));

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            foreach (var profile in profiles)
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(profile);
            }
        });

        container.Register<MapperConfiguration>(() => config);
        container.Register<IMapper>(() => container.GetInstance<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper());

        return container;
    }
}
```

I can then use DI for `IMapper` (or you could store it statically), as well as the `MapperConfiguration` for use in LINQ projections.

Comment: Is your `public static Container RegisterAutoMapper(this Container container)` contained in a class that inherits from Registry? or where does **AutoMapperRegistry** in `var profiles = typeof(AutoMapperRegistry).Assembly.GetTypes()...` from?@James

Comment: It is in a class called `AutoMapperRegistry` yes, although that class is only used to get some scope for finding `Profile` types in my application's assemblies. You could use something like this instead: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()...`

Comment: I'm using unity but I cant get to think how this is translated to unity
`container.Register<MapperConfiguration>(() => config);
        container.Register<IMapper>(() => container.GetInstance<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper());`

Comment: Not quite, that kinda veers off@James

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 
1.`container.Register<MapperConfiguration>(() => config);`
2.`container.Register<IMapper>(() => container.GetInstance<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper());` @James