# Conversion from Simple Injector to Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container, simple-injector, automapper-4

How does this Simple Injector code translate to unity. This is with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686955/migrating-to-automapper-4-2-1-from-automapper-2-2-1)

```
public static Container RegisterAutoMapper(this Container container)
{
    var profiles = typeof(AutoMapperRegistry).Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        .Select(t => (Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(t));

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
    });

    container.Register<MapperConfiguration>(() => config);
    container.Register<IMapper>(() => container.GetInstance<MapperConfiguration>()
        .CreateMapper());

    return container;
}
```

I believe the first part where we are scanning for profiles and looping through is pretty straightforward, I could be wrong. Something close to

```
public static Container RegisterAutoMapper(this Container container)
{
    var profiles = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                            .GetAssemblies()
                            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes());

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        foreach (var item in profiles)
        {
            if (item.FullName != "AutoMapper.SelfProfiler`2")
                cfg.AddProfile(Activator.CreateInstance(item) as Profile);
        }
    });


    //container.Resolve...;
    //container.Resolve...;

    return container;
}
```

How would we go about this using unity.

Comment: For the same reasons you chose SimpleInjector@Thomas

Comment: Sorry @mkaris, my comment was just for fun ^^